# Cannot expose mongodb objectId through wcf to mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mongodb, wcf, datacontractserializer

I'm facing an annoying problem while providing a wcf service. I am familiar with wcf and its usage.

Service Implementation:

```
public class Service : IService
{
    public SampleClass SampleMethod ( SampleClass sampleParameter )
    {
        return new SampleClass { MyProperty1 = Guid.NewGuid(), MyProperty2 = ObjectId.GenerateNewId() };
    }
}
```

Service interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    SampleClass SampleMethod ( SampleClass sampleParameter );
}
```

And my contract class:

```
/// this class is in DataContracts dll - meantioned in the exception
[DataContract]
public class SampleClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public Guid MyProperty1 { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public ObjectId MyProperty2 { get; set; }
}
```

I keep the interface and the contracts in seperate library projects and use the `dll`s at the clients.

MVC Side calling of service:

```
static IService Service = new ChannelFactory<IService>(new BasicHttpBinding("regularBinding"), new EndpointAddress(BaseAddress + "Service.svc")).CreateChannel();

public ActionResult Index()
{
    var xyz = Service.SampleMethod(new SampleClass());
    return View();
}
```

I can call this service from my unit test project or from a desktop application. But when I call the service from an MVC application it throws `ProtocolException`:

> An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:sampleParameter. The InnerException message was 'Error in line 1 position 451. 'EndElement' 'MyProperty2' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DataContracts' is not expected. Expecting element '_increment'.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.

I have a hunch that this is caused by some `serializer` related issue, but I don't really have deep understanding on those topics, so here I am.

What might be the cause of this behaviour? How can I overcome this without changing my data structures?

**Update**

Btw I realized that the exception occurs on return. When I throw an exception from within the service method, that exception propogates to the client. Therefore I can say my request with `ObjectId` can be received from the service but cannot return to the client.

Comment: My guess is that the clients doesn't know how to deserialize an objectId, since it resides on MongoDB.Bson.dll? http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/1.1/html/0a67129d-4e5a-4862-3e79-47e700658fab.htm

Comment: Try decorating your ObjectId property like this:

    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string MyProperty2 { get; set; }

Comment: MongoDB.Bson.dll is already included in client side - along with all other mongodb dlls. Let me try your suggestion.

Comment: Unfortunately not working. I've double checked with armful hopes, but no.

Comment: Can you post the code call from your MVC application?

Comment: Yeah sure but it is a basic call actually.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97293/discussion-between-jpgrassi-and-tolga-evcimen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've found out the problem and the solution in the discussion with @jpgrassi, but since @jpgrassi is too humble to post the answer, here I am.

Following the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866854/how-do-i-solve-this-error-error-while-trying-to-deserialize-parameter) @jeff's answer was inspiring enough to make me check the `MongoDB.Bson` dll's versions. There it was, they were different on server and mvc client and causing this problem. Leveling them on a version solved the problem.