# exceptions while calling WCF service from client

Tags: wcf

When I try to call the WCF on client machine it fails with the following exception. The funny part is sometimes it works perfectly fine. Can anyone assist me on this.

```
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameterPart(XmlDictionaryReader reader, PartInfo part, Boolean isRequest)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameter(XmlDictionaryReader reader, PartInfo part, Boolean isRequest)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBody(XmlDictionaryReader reader, MessageVersion version, String action, MessageDescription messageDescription, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeBodyContents(Message message, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeReply(Message message, Object[] parameters)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ProxyOperationRuntime.AfterReply(ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at FixedIncomeReconciliation.ServiceReference1.IFixedIncomeSettlementsService.GetDataService(DateTime date, String isRecon, String tabCaption)
   at FixedIncomeReconciliation.ServiceReference1.FixedIncomeSettlementsServiceClient.GetDataService(DateTime date, String isRecon, String tabCaption)
   at FixedIncomeReconciliation.ViewModel.MainConfirmsViewModel.ServiceCall(String isRecon, String tabCaption)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866854/how-do-i-solve-this-error-error-while-trying-to-deserialize-parameter See this same issue seems to be there..Depends upon what you want to serialize.